# NoSuchMethodError in google dataproc cluster for excel files

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

While consuming Excel file in dataproc cluster, getting error`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError`.

Note: schema is getting printed but not the actual data.

Error:

> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling
> o74.showString. : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> scala.Predef$.refArrayOps([Ljava/lang/Object;)Lscala/collection/mutable/ArrayOps;
> at
> com.crealytics.spark.excel.ExcelRelation.buildScan(ExcelRelation.scala:74)

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud import bigquery
import pyspark

client = storage.Client()

bucket_name = "test_bucket"

path=f"gs://{bucket_name}/test_file.xlsx"

def make_spark_session(app_name, jars=[]): 
  configuration = (SparkConf()     
            .set("spark.jars", ','.join(jars)))

  spark = SparkSession.builder.appName(app_name) \
    .config(conf=configuration).getOrCreate()
  return spark

app_name = 'test_app'
jars = ['gs://bucket/spark-excel_2.11_uber-0.12.0.jar']

spark = make_spark_session(app_name,jars)
df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel") \
          .option("useHeader","true") \
          .load(path)

df.show(1)
```

Comment: This appears to be Scala version mismatch between your job jars and the cluster. Which Dataproc version are you using? The spark-excel jar seems to be Scala 2.11 based.

Comment: I am using  Spark 3.1 Version, could you please provide the correct jars that need to used w.r.t this Pyspark compatibility.

Comment: I think you need spark_excel-2.12, you are currently using 2.11.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be Scala version mismatch between your job jars and the cluster. Both Dataproc [1.5](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-release-1.5) and [2.0](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/versioning/dataproc-release-2.0) come with Scala 2.12. The `gs://bucket/spark-excel_2.11_uber-0.12.0.jar` in your code seems to be Scala 2.11 based, you might want to use `spark-excel_2.12_...` instead. In addition to that, make sure your Spark application is also built with Scala 2.12.

Comment: I tried with 2.12 but getting below error
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o124.load.
: java.io.IOException: org/apache/commons/collections4/IteratorUtils

Comment: It's IOException, so could be IO related. Do you know the file path / URI associated with the exception? Have you tried accessing it without PySpark?